# Can't make very basic directed graph using cytoscape.js and react

Tags: reactjs, graph

I am a beginner to react and using external javascript libraries. I love it so far and I've been making a web app for information about the data structure graphs and algorithms about it. I am trying to make a very basic directed graph, but the arrows do not seem to show up. i can't find much information about making very basic graphs and have even tried copying code from their demos just to see if it would show up, but it still doesnt. If anyone has any idea, please let me know, I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<CytoscapeComponent
        elements={[
          { data: { id: "one", label: "Node 1" }, position: { x: 0, y: 0 } },
          { data: { id: "two", label: "Node 2" }, position: { x: 100, y: 0 } },
          {
            data: {
              source: "one",
              target: "two",
              label: "Edge from Node1 to Node2",
            },
          },
        ]}
        layout={{
          name: "breadthfirst",
          directed: true,
        }}
        style={{
          margin: "auto",
          height: "600px",
          width: "800px",
        }}
      />
```

and this is what comes up [image], just two nodes with no direction. I am using https://github.com/plotly/react-cytoscapejs but if there exists a solution with just the regular crytoscapejs its okay too! thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You need style the edges themselves in a stylesheet within your CytoscapeCompnent.  Be sure to incorporate the "targetArrowShape" and "curveStyle" props, like so:

```
<CytoscapeComponent 
    layout={{ name: "circle" }}
    elements={elements} 
    style={ { width: '600px', height: '600px' } } 

    stylesheet={[
      {
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
          width: 5,
          targetArrowShape: 'triangle',
          curveStyle: 'bezier'
        }
      }
    ]}
  />
```